# Armazenar todos os registros de uma tabela em uma variável (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, select, while, do-while

Preciso fazer uma consulta no meu banco de dados MySQL e armazenar todas as linhas que forem retornadas dentro da variável `$dadosBrutos`. O intuito é que cada linha seja separada pelo caractere "§", por exemplo:  `nomeCliente1,telefoneCliente1§nomeCliente2,telefoneCliente2§nomeCliente3,telefoneCliente3` e assim por diante.

Os dados serão obtidos com o comando `SELECT * FROM tbClientes`, mas não faço ideia de como separar uma linha da outra e armazenar elas dentro da variável `$dadosBrutos`.

Tentei fazer este código com `Do...While`, mas não faço ideia de como continuar.

Por enquanto possuo o seguinte código:

```
if($qtdeClientesCadastrados > 0) {  
    $contador = 0; 
    do {

    } while ($contador < $qtdeClientesCadastrados);
} else { 
    echo "zero_clientes_cadastrados";
}
```

**Observações:**

- A variável `$qtdeClientesCadastrados` já foi declarada no trecho acima do código postado e armazena a quantidade de clientes que estão cadastrados na `tbClientes` do banco de dados;
- Todo o sistema de conexão com o banco de dados já está criado e funcionando corretamente;
- Se houver algum método melhor para fazer o código sem ser com o `Do...While`, também serve, desde que no final seja possível dar o comando `echo $dadosBrutos;`.

Comment: O problema é separar com esse caractere `§`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- admitindo que os nomes das colunas sejam `cliente` e `telefone`
- Para o caractere `§` em todos os casos abaixo, utilizei `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1252");`

Tabela de exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**dados para conexao.php**

```
    $hostname="localhost";  
    $username="USUARIO";  
    $password="SENHA";  
    $db = "Nome_DB";
```

**Usando PDO**

```
$dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

$sql = "select cliente,telefone from tbClientes";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    do {
        $dadosBrutos .= $data['cliente'].','.$data['telefone'].'§'; 
        
    } while ($data = $stmt->fetch());

    $dadosBrutos= substr($dadosBrutos,0,-1); //AQUI ELIMINA O ULTIMO §

} else {
    $dadosBrutos= "zero_clientes_cadastrados";
}

echo $dadosBrutos;
```

**Usando mysqli**

```
$dbcon = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);
  
$query = $dbcon->query("select cliente,telefone from tbClientes");

$qtdeClientesCadastrados=mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

> opção 1

```
if($qtdeClientesCadastrados>0){

    do {
        $dadosBrutos .= $data['cliente'].','.$data['telefone'].'§'; 

    } while ($data = $query->fetch_array()); 
    
      $dadosBrutos=substr($dadosBrutos, 2); // elimina os dois primeiros caracteres (,§)
     $dadosBrutos= substr($dadosBrutos,0,-1); //AQUI ELIMINA O ULTIMO §

}else{
     $dadosBrutos= "zero_clientes_cadastrados";
}

echo $dadosBrutos;
```

> opção 2

```
if($qtdeClientesCadastrados>0){

    while($row = $query->fetch_array())
    {       
        $dadosBrutos .= $row['cliente'].','.$row['telefone'].'§'; 
    } 

     $dadosBrutos= substr($dadosBrutos,0,-1); //AQUI ELIMINA O ULTIMO §

}else{
     $dadosBrutos= "zero_clientes_cadastrados";
}

echo $dadosBrutos;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Objetivo: `echo $dadosBrutos;`

Solução feita com [implode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) em arrays resultantes da query.

Tentei simplificar ao máximo o código.

Caso não queria usar o $result como parâmetro da função, altere um pouco a função getDadosBrutos e use [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

```
<?php
    //Conexão apenas para exemplo
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT nomeCliente, telefoneCliente FROM tbClientes");
    $conn->close();

    //Joga a query na função para obter os dados concatenados
    $dadosBrutos = getDadosBrutos($query);

    //objetivo
    echo $dadosBrutos;

    function getDadosBrutos($result){
        $clientes = array();
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $clientes[] = implode(',',$row);
            }
        }else{
            //nenhum cliente
            return '';
        }
        return implode('§', $clientes);
    }
?>
```